# Wordpress home page resulting in 404 error

Tags: wordpress, iis, http-status-code-404

I've searched for this issue and nothing I have seen so far seems to be the same issue as me.

I have a Wordpress blog setup under a sub folder of a domain ( /development ). Everything works fine. I then changed the permalinks to nice links. Now everything still works fine, EXCEPT for the home page, which results in a 404 on the IIS server.

If I manually put "index.php" after it, the home page appears, but if I don't, it errors. The thing is, the home link that wordpress generates points only to "/" (which is actually what I want anyway).

Here's something interesting...if I then create an index.html file under the root of where Wordpress is and navigate to the home page again, I get the HTML file returned. It's almost as if this server doesn't default to index.php but will happily look for index.html.

I think this might be an issue with it being on IIS. How can I tell it to look for index.php as default?

I have no way of installing additional components / software and it's on a shared server. I don't mind having "index.php" but I'd like the home page to work without it.

Please help if you can.

Many thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in IIS7 you need to add index.php as a default document type. To do that

1. open IIS
2. select your website under Sites
3. Under IIS subcategory choose Default Document
4. Add index.php as a default document type.

IIS6 I don't know the answer, but I found this on SO. [Different Default Document Type in Subfolder on IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074383/different-default-document-type-in-subfolder-on-iis-6)

Answer (score 0):

Different ways of using - or not being able to use - permalinks on IIS: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

Be sure you are changing and saving permalinks from within Admin so the permalink setting is changed in the database, too.